# Cucumber how to run features multiple times with different code under test?

Tags: java, gradle, junit, cucumber

The shot version:
How do I do Junit's `@RunWith(Parameterized::class)` with cucumber features?

I have feature files that I like. I want to run the exact same features multiple times, but change "the environment" so the `@Before` code in my step-defs is slightly different. I have a few different implementations of some code under test, and I want to make sure they all work. So it has to be part of the CI pipeline. Not a manual cmd-line thing

The thing I want to change between runs has no semantic meaning to the scenarios/features file, so I would prefer not to radically alter/duplicate them.

I'm using stock java/kotlin and gradle junit. No spring, no webUI

I setup multiple junit hooks all pointing to the same features, which works for running the features multiple times. But I can't figure out how to get any information from the hook to the step-defs.

--- update ---

Here is the code I have to plug the cucumber tests into junit :

```
@RunWith(Cucumber::class)
@CucumberOptions(
    features = ["src/test/resources/hellocucumber/"],
)
class FirstRun

@RunWith(Cucumber::class)
@CucumberOptions(
    features = ["src/test/resources/hellocucumber/"],
)
class SecondRun
```

This does run the tests twice, which is what I want.

But in my step-defs I the `@Before` section were I setup the code under test, how do I tell if it's the first run, or the second? I can't figure out a way to get any data from these stubs to the step-defs.

Maybe this isn't the way to do this?

Comment: Can you show us some code to reproduce the scenario what you are doing?

Comment: Take the "Is it Friday" example from the docs. I want to run that multiple times, but have the code-under-test use a different time library each time. The expectation is that the test and its results should not change. I can't figure out how to do this. If your doing BDD, then it seems odd to imbed this information into the scenarios. They shouldn't care about implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

What about using environment variables to modify your before code, and then instead of trying to cucumber to run features multiple times, script to run cucumber multiple times each with a different environment variables.

You can either user different values for ENV vars. Or even different sets of ENV vars.

Your features will know which run they are in from ENV,

Comment: yeah, that makes sense. But now I've just pushed the problem back to gradle, Which isn't a bastion of simplicity. Especially if you still want your tests to run in parallel.